# Is it better to upgrade to XCode 9 from xCode 8 or just delete the old version and install the new one

Tags: xcode8, xcode9

I am new to IOS development and just got started two months ago with XCode 8 and yet Apple just released XCode 9 on the AppStore and on the developer website and I want to upgrade to it. The problem is I have a mac with a 249 GB hard drive with a current free space 160 GB and the new XCode version (XCode 9) is 5 GB. My question is, is it gonna take a larger space if I upgraded to XCode 9 from the AppStore or I just can delete XCode 8 and download and install XCode 9 as a fresh new App. If there is an optimal way to upgrade to XCode 9 without taking larger space on the hard disk please tell me.

Comment: Updating XCode is not incremental. Delete  + Reinstall is less space than Overwrite because Appstore first downloads THEN overwrites.. So before the download completes, you'll have two versions of XCode. After it is finished, you will be left with one. The end result is the same.

Comment: so u say that I just need to upgrade my xcode 8 to xcode 9 from the AppStore with no worries of taking much larger space right?

Comment: @loaymansour Just upgrade, it will take space only in the process of upgrading, when it will finish upgrading, it will use 5 GB only like your old XCode was using.

Comment: Ok thanks @iphonic